# Скрипт python (секундомер с графическим интерфейсом) работает на Windows 10. но не работает на Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: python

Скрипт python (секундомер с графическим интерфейсом) работает на Windows 10. но не работает на Linux Mint Cinnamon. Переименовывать в .py пробовал - не помогает. Tkinter установлен. Результат попытки запуска в терминале вот такой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код такой. Что с ним может быть не так? Заранее спасибо!

```html
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

temp = 0
after_id = ""


def tick():
    global temp, after_id
    after_id = root.after(1000, tick)
    f_temp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(temp).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    label1.configure(text=str(f_temp))
    temp += 1


def start_sw():
    btn1.grid_forget()
    btn2.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
    tick()


def stop_sw():
    btn2.grid_forget()
    btn3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
    btn4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
    root.after_cancel(after_id)


def continue_sw():
    btn3.grid_forget()
    btn4.grid_forget()
    btn2.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
    tick()


def reset_sw():
    global temp
    temp = 0
    label1.configure(text="00:00:00")
    btn3.grid_forget()
    btn4.grid_forget()
    btn1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")


root = Tk()

root.title("Секундомер")

label1 = Label(root, width=7, font=("Ubuntu", 42), text="00:00:00")
label1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

btn1 = Button(root, text="Старт", font=("Ubuntu", 12), fg='green', bg='white', command=start_sw)
btn2 = Button(root, text="Стоп", font=("Ubuntu", 12), fg='red', bg='white', command=stop_sw)
btn3 = Button(root, text="Продолжить", font=("Ubuntu", 12), fg='green', bg='white', command=continue_sw)
btn4 = Button(root, text="Сбросить", font=("Ubuntu", 12), bg='white', command=reset_sw)

btn1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: а запуск через `python3 sekundomer.py` работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Установите пакеты Python3, а также Tkinter:

```
sudo apt install python3
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

2. Укажите путь к интерпретатору вставив следующее в начало Вашего файла:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

3. Сделайте Ваш файл исполняемым:

```
chmod +x имявашегофайла.py
```

После этого все должно работать. Я проверил это на моей системе Debian GNU/Linux 11 Bullseye, все запустилось.
P.S.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пусть к интерпретатору указал. Мне кажется проблема в этом, т.к. и права стояли и Python с Tkinter были установлены.

Сейчас получаю вот такую ошибку:
"(base) xeon@xeon-desktop:~$ ./sekundomer.py 
bash: ./sekundomer.py: /usr/bin/python3^M: неверный интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога". Почему в пути появилось ^M не знаю. Пробовал несколько раз по-разному сохранять.

Comment: Судя по тому, что я нашел тут может помочь dos2unix. Было бы хорошо понять, как это сделать в PyCharm или Sublime.

Comment: Пока получилось сделать так:
`sudo apt install dos2unix
dos2unix ./sekundomer.py`

gth-other, спасибо!